# Post Processing with three.js and expo on React Native

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo, post-processing

Is there a way to get post-processing effects to work with expo-three? I can get normal code without post-processing to work without trouble, but as soon as I add effects, they seem to do nothing. I've tested the similar code for web and it works perfectly.

My code in Test.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { GLView, ExpoWebGLRenderingContext } from 'expo-gl'
import { Renderer } from 'expo-three'
import {
  AmbientLight,
  BoxBufferGeometry,
  Fog,
  GridHelper,
  Mesh,
  MeshLambertMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  PointLight,
  Scene,
  SpotLight,
  Vector2,
  Color
} from 'three'

import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass'
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer'
import { OutlinePass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutlinePass'

const Test = () => {
  let timeout

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Clear the animation loop when the component unmounts
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [])
  return (
    <GLView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      onContextCreate={async (gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
        const { drawingBufferWidth: width, drawingBufferHeight: height } = gl
        const sceneColor = 0x6ad6f0

        // Create a WebGLRenderer without a DOM element
        const renderer = new Renderer({ gl })
        renderer.setSize(width, height)
        renderer.setClearColor(sceneColor)

        const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 0.01, 1000)
        camera.position.set(2, 5, 5)

        const scene = new Scene()
        scene.fog = new Fog(sceneColor, 1, 10000)
        scene.add(new GridHelper(10, 10))

        const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer)

        const renderPass = new RenderPass(scene, camera)
        composer.addPass(renderPass)

        const outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new Vector2(width, height), scene, camera)
        composer.addPass(outlinePass)

        outlinePass.edgeStrength = 5
        outlinePass.edgeThickness = 1
        outlinePass.edgeGlow = 1
        outlinePass.pulsePeriod = 4
        outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor = new Color('#ffffff')
        outlinePass.hiddenEdgeColor = new Color('#919191')

        const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0x101010)
        scene.add(ambientLight)

        const pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000, 1)
        pointLight.position.set(0, 200, 200)
        scene.add(pointLight)

        const spotLight = new SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
        spotLight.position.set(0, 500, 100)
        spotLight.lookAt(scene.position)
        scene.add(spotLight)

        const cube = new IconMesh()
        scene.add(cube)
        outlinePass.selectedObjects = [cube]

        camera.lookAt(cube.position)

        function update() {
          cube.rotation.y += 0.05
          cube.rotation.x += 0.025
        }

        // Setup an animation loop
        const render = () => {
          timeout = requestAnimationFrame(render)
          update()
          composer.render()
          gl.endFrameEXP()
        }
        render()
      }}
    />
  )
}

class IconMesh extends Mesh {
  constructor() {
    super(
      new BoxBufferGeometry(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
      new MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'blue' })
    )
  }
}

export default Test
```

My dependencies:

```
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.3.1",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-av": "^7.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-gl": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-graphics": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-three": "^5.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "three": "^0.110.0"
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried getting it to work outside of the React environment? I feel like adding that extra layer of complexity makes the question more difficult to debug, and goes against the spirit of creating a [minimal example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Marquizzo This is a minimal example. The code works fine on web. My question simply asks if post-processing is available on React Native with expo-three or any other library. I can't remove React/React Native because that is a requirement for the project.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you were just having problems with `EffectComposer`, but it sounds like it works well in vanilla JS, but not when you use it with `expo-three`. My question is, what version of Three.js are you running? Also, looks like [expo-gl was deprecated a year ago](https://github.com/expo/expo-gl) and Three.js has changed the way it handles setting `renderTargets` in the last few months, which is a big part of `EffectComposer`.

Comment: @Marquizzo I updated my question with my project dependencies.